# How to keep looping with try and catch to get correct input?

Tags: java, input, while-loop, integer, try-catch

I'm trying to make a function that checks for an integer and will keep looping until the user correctly enters an integer of 17 or higher. However, if I put in wrong input, like 'K', or '&', it will get stuck in an infinite loop.

```
public static int getAge(Scanner scanner) {
    int age;
    boolean repeat = true;

    while (repeat) {
        try
        {
          System.out.println("Enter the soldier's age: ");
          age = scanner.nextInt();
          repeat = false;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException exception)
        {
          System.out.println("ERROR: You must enter an age of 17 or higher");
          repeat = true;
        }
    }
    return age;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to use Try catch in a while loop until the user answers correctly without entering invalid data(Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27208796/trying-to-use-try-catch-in-a-while-loop-until-the-user-answers-correctly-without)

Comment: Whats the problem with your solution is it not working .You forgot to ask a question

Answer (score 2):

If next available input token isn't an integer, `nextInt()` leaves that input unconsumed, buffered inside the `Scanner`. The idea is that you might want to try to read it with some other `Scanner` method, such as `nextDouble()`.  Unfortunately, this also means that unless you do something to get rid of the buffered-up garbage, your next call to `nextInt()` will will just try (and fail) to read the same junk over again.

So, to flush out the junk, you need to call either `next()` or `nextLine()` before trying to call `nextInt()` again.  This ensures that the next time you call `nextInt()`, it will have new data to work on instead of the same old garbage:

```
try {
    //...
} 
catch(InputMismatchException exception)
{
    System.out.println("ERROR: You must enter an age of 17 or higher");
    scanner.next();   // or scanner.nextLine()
    repeat = true;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I'm still getting used to how the Scanner works.

Answer (score 0):

I would not pass a scanner to your method I would try re structuring it, and assigning the method to a variable in your main like this:

I am also using recursion in my catch to recall the method when the exception is caught, id also recommend using maybe a general exception , making it catch(Exception exception)

```html
  main method call of method
    ---------------------------
        int something= getAge();
        ----------------------------------------------------------

         method structure like this,
    ---------------------------------------------

        public static int getAge() {
            int age;
    age = scanner.nextInt();
            boolean repeat = true;

            while (repeat) {
                try
                {
                  System.out.println("Enter the soldier's age: ");
                  
                   
        if(age<=17){
                  repeat = false;
        }

    if(age>17){


    getAge();
    }
                }
                catch(InputMismatchException exception)
                {
                  System.out.println("ERROR: You must enter an age of 17 or higher");
                  getAge();
                }

            }
            return age;
        }
```

```
<!-- end snippet -->
```

Comment: Any thoughts or comments guys? Im also a beginner to java, what do you think of my solution?