# Java, while infinite loop when using scanner

Tags: java, loops, input, while-loop

I want to ask the user to enter a String, and four integer values, and i want the program to keep asking the user for integer value if the user input a type mismatch, why the code keep looping forever and never wait for the user input if the user inserted a wrong type ?

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sessionName;
    int pomoInterv, breakInterv, terminalBreakInterv;
    System.out.println("Please, Enter the session name: ");
    sessionName = scanner.nextLine();
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please, Enter the Pomodoro interval: ");
            pomoInterv = scanner.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please, Enter the break interval: ");
            breakInterv = scanner.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    while (true){
        try {
            System.out.println("Please, Enter the terminal break interval ");
            terminalBreakInterv = scanner.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
    System.out.println(sessionName);
    System.out.println(pomoInterv);
    System.out.println(breakInterv);
    System.out.println(terminalBreakInterv);

}
}
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat I don't think this is a dupe of that question, though they have the same answer. There's probably a better dupe target somewhere...

Comment: Use a library for this sort of stuff. I can recommend [picocli](https://picocli.info/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to scanner oracle docs :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

When a scanner throws an InputMismatchException, the scanner will not pass the token that caused the exception, so that it may be retrieved or skipped via some other method.

So when you entered anything other than an integer, the scanner.nextInt() will not parse it to integer and throw InputMismatchException and the scanner will not move to the next token and tried to read again and again the same token.

To solve this, you can either change the loop or use hasNextInt() method or use scanner.next() in the catch block so that the scanner can move to the next token.

Answer (score 0):

I always use do-while loop when checking for correct Input from the user.

See if the following works:

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sessionName;
    int pomoInterv = -1, breakInterv = -1, terminalBreakInterv = -1;
    System.out.println("Please, Enter the session name: ");
    sessionName = scanner.nextLine();
    boolean isPomoInterv = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please, Enter the Pomodoro interval: ");
        String temp = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            if (Integer.parseInt(temp) > 0) {
                pomoInterv = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                isPomoInterv = true;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }

    } while (!isPomoInterv);

    boolean isBreakInterv = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please, Enter the break interval: ");
        String temp = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            if (Integer.parseInt(temp) > 0) {
                breakInterv = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                isBreakInterv = true;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }

    } while (!isBreakInterv);

    boolean isTerminalBreakInterv = false;
    do {
        System.out.println("Please, Enter the terminal break interval ");
        String temp = scanner.nextLine();
        try {
            if (Integer.parseInt(temp) > 0) {
                terminalBreakInterv = Integer.parseInt(temp);
                isTerminalBreakInterv = true;
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Try again");
        }

    } while (!isTerminalBreakInterv);

    System.out.println("Done!");
    System.out.println(sessionName);
    System.out.println(pomoInterv);
    System.out.println(breakInterv);
    System.out.println(terminalBreakInterv);
```

The comment on your question by [scary-wombat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2310289/scary-wombat) is correct. i have used his comment to code the above.

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it, i just had to add a (scanner.next();) in the catch statement as below, it's because how the Scanner class works, see the code below,

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String sessionName;
    int pomoInterv, breakInterv, terminalBreakInterv;
    System.out.println("Please, Enter the session name: ");
    sessionName = scanner.nextLine();
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please, Enter the Pomodoro interval: ");
            pomoInterv = scanner.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            scanner.next();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    while (true) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Please, Enter the break interval: ");
            breakInterv = scanner.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            scanner.next();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
    while (true){
        try {
            System.out.println("Please, Enter the terminal break interval ");
            terminalBreakInterv = scanner.nextInt();
            break;
        } catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
            scanner.next();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Done!");
    System.out.println(sessionName);
    System.out.println(pomoInterv);
    System.out.println(breakInterv);
    System.out.println(terminalBreakInterv);

}
}
```

check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47852703/12565862

Answer (score -1):

Because you don't have a `break;` in catch block. When there is exception, you print the message. But once it comes out of catch block, while loop still satisfies its condition and execute again. Try adding `break;` inside catch block too.

Comment: it's most likely because your answer is wrong. yes, the while would continue, the user would enter new information and proceed.